# Task Cleanup Agent doesn't clean up everything

Tags: scheduled-tasks

The task cleanup agent is running as per the schedule but it is ignoring certain files.

It seems to delete files that have recently expired but it doesn't seem to remove files that are really old.

This means we are getting very large log file directories. Has anyone experienced this problem where the CleanUp Agent isn't removing all the files that it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is log files the issue ? Make sure the pattern is `*log.*.txt` according to the names of the newest log files, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cleanup everything then your pattern should be `pattern="*.*"` and you can also set `recursive="true"` if you want to cleanup sub directories too.

Example -

```
<remove folder="$(dataFolder)/logs" pattern="*.*" maxAge="07.00:00:00" recursive="true" />
```